# Can the audio jack of the Raspberry Pi 2 play ultrasounds?

Tags: audio

Does any one know if the Raspberry Pi 2 is capable of playing frequencies over 40Khz from the audio jack?

Answer (score 2):

No;

The pi B and B+ get a lot of THD around 10kHz ([ref](http://www.crazy-audio.com/2014/07/sound-quality-of-the-raspberry-pi-b/)).

The Hifiberry claims 192kHz ([ref](https://www.hifiberry.com/dacplus)) but fails to show a frequency response curve.

Some Linux is not supporting anything over 192kHz ([ref](http://www.crazy-audio.com/2015/05/384khz-playback-on-the-raspberry-pi/)).

The HiFi Shield for C2/C1+ will do 50kHz ([ref](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G143729448865)).

No Pi has a dedicated DAC ([ref](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=745598#p745598)) so sound is PWMed to about 11 bit 10kHz.

So, if someone made an amplitude fall off curve for an external DAC, and you found a suitable amplifier and [speakers](http://www.head-fi.org/t/177655/help-needed-inexpensive-speakers-with-bandwidth-to-50-khz), it might be worth a try.

Comment: so by using the HiFi shield i could get it up to 50Khz ?